# cannot import name 'set_config' from 'jcopdl.callback'

Tags: python, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import `set_config` from `jcopdl.callback`. But it is giving the error `cannot import name 'set_config' from 'jcopdl.callback'

I installed `jcopdl` using `pip3 install jcopdl`

I am able to import other libraries like

```
from jcopdl.callback import Callback
from jcopdl.layers import linear_block, conv_block`
```

I tried upgrading also using `pip3 install --upgrade jcopdl`
It has not worked.

Did 'set_config' removed from `jcopdl`. If so, how to import 'set_config'

Answer (score 0):

The creator of this package confirmed that Version 1.1.10 supports set_config. I tried and it is working.

Upgrade your jcopdl version using following
pip install --upgrade jcopdl==1.1.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).